# Remove duplicate rows based on dynamic amount of columns

Tags: vba, excel

I got the total number of columns, and tried to append it to string in such a way it is 1,2,3,4,5 depending on the number of columns.

```
Sub DeleteHighlightedRecords()

 numofCol = ""

     For i = 1 To lcol

        numofCol = numofCol & "," & i

     Next i

 numofCol = Mid(numofCol, 2)

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(numofCol), Header:=xlNo
End Sub
```

The above code i have will match the combination i placed in Array(), and then remove the duplicates ya? Correct me if i am wrong, however I am getting application-defined error.

How may i set the dynamic numbers of columns into the Array()?

Comment: passing the columns argument to `RemoveDuplicates` is tricky. What error are you getting, exactly? @Ralph: It's not about removing the duplicates from the array but from the columns specified by the array.

Comment: I am getting Runtime Error 1004 if you are interested to know, however @arcadeprecinct already provided the solution below.

Comment: Yeah that's me ;-) I was just curious because I was getting multiple uncommon errors while testing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Array(1,2,3)` is not the same as `Array("1,2,3")`. The first will produce an 3-element array containing 1,2 and 3, the second will produce an 1-element array containing the string `"1,2,3"`.

To create an actual array we can do the following:

```
    Dim numOfCol() As Variant 'normally I would choose Long instead of variant but that gave a type mismatch error
    Dim i As Long   'always use "Option Explicit" at the top of your module!
    ReDim numOfCol(0 To (lcol - 1))  'has to be 0-based for RemoveDuplicates

    For i = 0 To (lcol - 1)
        numOfCol(i) = i + 1
    Next i
```

Now as if using a `Variant` array instead of a `Long` array and using a 0-based array wasn't enough, `RemoveDuplicates` apparently also can't handle arguments passed as a reference to a variable instead of a value. To pass a variable as a value rather than a reference, encase it in parentheses. This causes the variable to be evaluated and then passed to the function.

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=(numOfCol), Header:=xlNo
```

Comment: Thanks @arcadeprecinct for your advice. It works like a charm.